# Singleton object destroys in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, singleton, application-start

I need to do some updates just once after starting ASP.NET MVC application. I've created the singleton instance:

```
public sealed class SingletonClass
{
    private static readonly Object s_lock = new Object();
    private static SingletonClass instance = null;

    private SingletonClass()
    { }

    public static SingletonClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance != null) return instance;

            Monitor.Enter(s_lock);
            SingletonClass temp = new SingletonClass();
            temp.isSomeDataUpdated = false;
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref instance, temp);
            Monitor.Exit(s_lock);
            return instance;
        }
    }

    private bool isSomeDataUpdated;

    public void RefreshIfFirstExecution()
    {
        if (!isSomeDataUpdated) 
        { 
            isSomeDataUpdated = true;
            Refresh(); 
        }
    }

    private void Refresh() { ... }
}
```

and tried to execute it's **RefreshIfFirstExecution()** method, first from **Global.asax** --> **Application_Start()** method, then from **Startup.cs** --> **Configuration()**, even from **BaseController**'s constructor. But I've got the same problem: after home page was displayed, when I try to navigate any next page, my **instance** object equals **null** again.

What have I done wrong and how to execute **Refresh()** method only once after application starting?

**Updated**

The instance begin include object, when I've changed the way of calling:

```
SingletonClass.Instance.RefreshIfFirstExecution();
```

to

```
var singletonRefresher = SingletonClass.Instance;
singletonRefresher.RefreshIfFirstExecution();
```

but **isSomeDataUpdated** equals **false** even after first execution of **RefreshIfFirstExecution()** method (which sets it to **true**). **isSomeDataUpdated** variable is the part of class (and, as result, the part of instance). As I understand, after first **RefreshIfFirstExecution()** it should be always **true**, am I right? What have I missed?

**Updated2:**

**SingletonClass.Instance** becomes null for every new request, **BUT(!)** if I move mouse over it in debug mode, it generates new object (breakpoint on **Instance**'s **get{}** method doesn't trigger). I've returned back to the question "Why the SingletonClass.Instance object equals null?"

P.S. Alexey's singleton implementation haven't solved this problem

Comment: Can you share the implementation of `Refresh` method?

Comment: hadn't write updation for `isSomeDataUpdated` variable in `RefreshIfFirstExecution()` method. I've corrected it. The `Refresh()` method's implementation isn't important. It doesn't touch singleton logic

Comment: You want to figure out how to call Refresh method properly while also worried about why `instance` is returning null. So if they are not related then how are they related ?

Comment: @Vitaliy can you please implement firstly your singleton correctly for multithreaded app?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx
check "Multithreaded Singleton" section.

Comment: @Alexey It works the same, but thanks for another singleton implementation.

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya They are related with `private bool isSomeDataUpdated` field. After first refresh calling this field sets to `true` and another refreshes should be impossible. Read **Updated** section, please

Comment: @Vitaliy if you still have field with false value then you have not the same instance. It's hardly possible even in your example, but still possible that singleton instance will be created several times.
this check `if (instance != null) return instance;` is not a bulletproof check. When instance is null next code segment can be accessed via several threads at the same time, as result you have several instances of your "singleton"

Interlocked already provides thread safe method, this lock does nothing.

Comment: @Alexey I run these requests manually one by another from browser (by calling different pages)

Comment: @Vitaliy if you create empty new MVC app will you get the same?

Comment: @Alexey In new project it works as should. And Global.asax --> Application_Start() executes just only ones on application start (in current project it executes for every new user's request)